# aiogram: How to group, format and send multiple dictionaries

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram

You need to send separate messages schedule for different days.
Here is an example input:

```
raspisanie = [{'week_day': 'Monday, 'name': 'Lesson 1', 'time': '8:30'}, {'week_day': 'Tuesday', name: 'Lesson 1', 'time': '8:30'}, {'week_day': 'Tuesday', name: 'Lesson 2', 'time': '10:30'}])
```

I can’t figure out how to send one SMS every day so that it looks like this:

*First SMS:
Monday
Lesson 1
8:30
Second SMS:
Tuesday
Lesson 1
8:30
Lesson 2
10:30*

Only the cycle inside message.answer comes to mind, but this is not possible.
I will be glad for any help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better usage, it is better to save week_day as index. `Monday = 0, Tuesday = 1, Wednesday = 2, ... , Sunday = 6`. If you still want to keep it as a word, you can write a function to convert the name of the weekday to the index, it is not a big deal tho.

```
import datetime
import asyncio


def get_schedule_for_today(schedule: list, current_day: int) -> list:
    schedule_for_today = []

    for lesson in schedule:
        if lesson['week_day'] == current_day:
            schedule_for_today.append(lesson)

    return schedule_for_today


async def daily_worker():
    schedule = [{'week_day': 0, 'name': 'Lesson 1', 'time': '8:30'},
                {'week_day': 1, 'name': 'Lesson 1', 'time': '8:30'},
                {'week_day': 1, 'name': 'Lesson 2', 'time': '10:30'}]

    schedule_for_today = get_schedule_for_today(schedule, datetime.datetime.today().weekday())
    while True:
        current_hour_minute = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")

        if current_hour_minute == '00:00':
            schedule_for_today = get_schedule_for_today(schedule, datetime.datetime.today().weekday())

        for lesson in schedule_for_today:
            if lesson['time'] == current_hour_minute:
                await bot.send_message(chat_id=100, text=f"{lesson['name']}")

        await asyncio.sleep(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # register new thread to 'executor'
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(daily_worker())

    executor.start_polling(dp, loop = loop)
```